# Why did .ToString("MMM dd yyyy") go from "Jul" to "July" (aka how do I report a bug / see change log for .net)

Tags: .net, datetime, .net-core, tostring, cultureinfo

Prior to recent Windows 11 Update when I had code that was DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy") the output would be "Jul 12 2022" but recently it has started to produce "July 12 2022" (this is on the same machine; with culture en-AU before and after the update)

It appears to only be when one does that with more than just "MMM" i.e. DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM") still produces "Jul" but adding the "dd yyyy" makes it "July"

This looks to be some odd combination of culture specific and Windows 11 Updates as: I still get "Jul" if: machine is running Windows 10, machine is set to en-US; but if Windows 11 and latest updates and en-AU then "July 12 2022" for "MMM dd yyyy"

The "easy" solution (if you've come here and are en-AU and having the same issue) is to add CultureInfo.Invariant to the call: so DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.Invariant)

The extended questions are:

- How was one to know about this change? I've looked at Windows 11 Update logs and similar and don't see anything about this change; have we been informed of this change?
- If it is a bug; what is the right way to submit a bug (other than stackoverflow so others see a sign-post) to have that looked at?

Comment: The `MMM` specifier is dependent on the culture of the machine, this is not a bug. What culture is your machine set to?

Comment: @DavidG yes I know, the issue is that the machine culture didn't change (was en-AU before is en-AU now) but the output changed since the last Windows 11 Update; I've updated question to clarify, thanks

Comment: I'm curious what you get if you look at `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames`?

Comment: Confirmed - seems to be the same behaviour for June, getting "June 12 2021" instead of "Jun 12 2021"

Comment: Looks like it uses `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` rather than `AbbreviatedMonthNames`. I have confirmed that Win10 genitive names are all 3 letters for en-AU but Win11 has some of them with 4 letters.

Comment: @DavidG it looks like Win 11 a month ago had all 3 letter as well; any idea why that might have changed?

Comment: @DavidG what's particularly odd is that it looks like it uses AbbreviatedMonthNames when you just use "MMM" but AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames when you use "MMM dd yyyy"

Comment: I think that is on purpose. Genitive suggests the names belong or relate to something else. So adding in the `dd yyyy` part makes the day 'belong' to the month. On it's own there is nothing to belong to, so it reverts to the non-genitive name. That's a guess.

Comment: @DavidG sure that makes sense for when to use Genitive vs other (thanks for that info); but why did Genitive change (and where does one see that change coming for future changes like this) from month to month in Windows 11?

Comment: A little bit of reading on genitive names and I think I am right about the meaning. As for why Windows 11 changed it.... that's a mystery to me!

Comment: Anyway, I tried to summarise my comments in an answer.

Comment: @DavidG makes sense as to what / why ... but the fact that code was working one way three weeks ago and with no code change now works a different way ... the question of how does one get informed (no release notes seem to mention this) or if this is unintentional how we report this to revert back

Comment: Well, it's not a bug in the OS or .NET, but it *might* be an issue with how Windows collects the culture info. No idea how/where that comes from or how you would report an issue. Maybe the official Windows forums?

Comment: @ChrisHDog .NET Core is open source so if you want to report an issue, go to the Github repo. Make sure it's an actual bug though. `ToString()` is culture-sensitive and the docs go to great lengths to warn people about this. I can't reproduce this [in dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LtwIxV) which uses Linux, so this seems like a Windows 11 change.

Comment: @ChrisHDog turns out [this is the defined Unicode CLDR behavior](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/7de60bb8e23cfc3e6129919f9e823c5b13ba8552/common/main/en_AU.xml#L1771). In a formatted string in en-AU, the abbreviated July name is `July`. The old behavior was wrong. If anything, you should be asking why `MMM yyyy` doesn't return `July 2022` as well

Comment: @ChrisHDog [this related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65824) explains that .NET uses the standard Unicode CLDR format specification to format dates the same across OSs. For some reason, June and July aren't abbreviated in Australia. I'd suspect there's a reason `MMM yyyy` behaves the way it does too but I'm not a Unicode lawyer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks so much, that makes sense; it would have been nice to see that in some release notes or update (anyone know if it is somewhere); wondering how many little software issues are cropping up in Australia as they relied on the old behavior for some reason or another

Comment: @ChrisHDog it *was* [announced by The Time Lord himself](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis) a year ago but I guess people didn't realize what the changes meant. Or thought it's only some JavaScript quirk, nothing to do with us. (MJP is one of the maintainers of NodaTime)

Comment: If you think that's strange, try `30000000.45.ToString("##,###.00",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ZA"))`

Comment: I got this strange behavior after upgrading a unit test project from .net framework 4.8 to .net 5 under win 10 x64 for example `new DateTime(2023, 6, 12).ToString("ddd, dd.MMM")`.
With .net 4.8 it prints `Mo., 12.Jun` and with .net5 it prints `Mo, 12.Juni` (the dot is missing and the month-name got longer) for german locale.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't a bug with .NET or Windows 11, it's really a quirk of how dates are represented in text form. Date formats in .NET support the concept of genitive names for month names. In certain cultures the way the month is written changes depending on how you write it out. In English there is no difference but in a language like Latvian for example, writing "January" and "14th January" will result in different spellings ("janvāris" and "janvārī")

If you look at the `DateTimeFormat` for a `CultureInfo` object, you will see two properties: `AbbreviatedMonthNames` and `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames`. They are arrays of how each month is represented in text form. For `en-GB`, both of those arrays are the same and contain `Jan',` Feb`,` Mar` etc.

However, for some reason, Windows 11 has a different set of names for some months and uses 4 letters for June, July and Sept.

So this code:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU");
Console.WriteLine(culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames[6]);
```

Will output `Jul` in Windows 10 and `July` in Windows 11. Why they are different, I have no idea!

Comment: It seems there *is* a bug. `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU").DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(DateTime.Today.Month)` returns `Jul` and `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM yyyy",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"))` returns `Jul 2022` but `MMM dd` returns `July 10`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not a bug, the genetive names are only used when the day is included in the format string.

Comment: It seems this is also [part of the Unicode standard](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/7de60bb8e23cfc3e6129919f9e823c5b13ba8552/common/main/en_AU.xml#L1771). For AU in a format context, June and July aren't abbreviated. Why doesn't `MMM yyyy` use `July` then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When you write "July 2020" the month doesn't "belong" to the year (in terms of grammar) but "12th July" is a shortened form of saying "The twelfth *of* July". Note that the day is *of* the month. And good spot on that link, note that below are the standalone abbreviations which use only 3 letters.